# Prove the set is not connected

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

Let $\gamma:[a;b]\to\mathbb{R}^2$ is jordan curve. Proof $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\mathrm{Im}(\gamma)$ is not connected.

Here, Jordan curve is a closed simple continuous plane curve.

I think because $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\mathrm{Im}(\gamma)$ is union of two open sets but i don't show that?

Answer (score 0):

You are right: since $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\operatorname{Im}(\gamma)$ is the union of two (disjoint) open sets, it cannot be connected. To be more precise: if $X$ is a topological space and if $A_1$ and $A_2$ are disjoint non-empty subsets of $X$, then $A_1\cup A_2$ is not connected (with respect to the induced topology), since $A_1\cup A_2$ is the union of two open disjoint subsets, none of which is empty.

Comment: how can I show that $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \mathrm{Im}(\gamma)$ is the union of two (disjoint) open sets?

Comment: @Flower Apply the [Jordan curve theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_curve_theorem).

Comment: while I prove Jordan curve theorem, I need to $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \mathrm{Im}(\gamma)$ is not connected?

Comment: @Flower I don't know what is it that you mean. Nobody is expecting that you prove the Jordan curve theorem.

Comment: can we prove that it is not connected without using Jordan Curve Theorem?

Comment: @Flower I don't think so.